# How do I choose the best answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I recently asked [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/24829/how-can-one-not-let-their-voice-show-through-in-all-the-characters) and got six answers that seem pretty reasonable.  I didn't have a specific answer in mind and there probably won't be many results from the advice for a while.

**How do I decide which is the better answer in this particular case?**

Answer (score 4):

Accepting an answer is meant to say that the answer was the most useful to you personally; it's okay to leave it unchecked if you don't have a preference. Accepting an answer also doesn't mean you can't change your mind later if a better answer comes along.

In this case, I'd definitely find some of the posted answers more helpful than others. But that's me.

You can find more in the help center: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I'd like to add that you don't have to choose an answer immediately. I often don't know which answer will be the most helpful before I have tried the advice I have received. There are questions where I have accepted an answer several years after I asked them.

Comment: I do have one question on GDSE I've left open for two years (as of right now) because I still haven't found an answer. I don't like to leave it open, but so far none of the suggestions have worked for me.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Maybe you will accept my answer? :-)

Comment: @what Can you hack together something which works exactly like iBiz? and not charge hundreds of dollars for? :) Because iBiz was about $45, give or take, and as a single programmer doing a custom job you'd be perfectly justified in charging $250 and up.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Ah, well, okay, I guess not...